# Join line to point automatically with ArcGIS

Tags: arcpy, point, snapping, polyline-creation

Is there a possibility in ArcGIS to join automatically line with point, for example, with the image below?

[image]

Comment: You want to research the "snap" and/or "snapping" capabilities.

Answer (score 3):

As Vince suggested. The tool you probably are interested in using is the [Snap geoprocessing tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/editing/snap.htm). This tool will allow you to snap line's end-vertex to a point. It will also allow you to create preferential snapping; if there isn't a point nearby, then snap to the nearest line end-vertex instead.

[image]